# Qt::CheckStateRole in QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, qml

I tried to derive a model from `QFileSystemModel`, added a `CheckBox` to the delegate displayed in a `TreeView` and wanted to save the state of the checkbox in the Qt::CheckStateRole. However, 
Why is it not possible to use the `Qt::CheckStateRole` in a `QFileSystemModel`? I added the CheckStateRole to my derived model:

```
QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
{
     QHash<int, QByteArray> result = QFileSystemModel::roleNames();
     result.insert(UrlStringRole, QByteArrayLiteral("urlstring"));
     result.insert(SizeRole, QByteArrayLiteral("size"));
     result.insert(LastModifiedRole, QByteArrayLiteral("lastModified"));
     result.insert(IsDirRole, QByteArrayLiteral("isDir"));
     result.insert(Qt::CheckStateRole,QByteArrayLiteral("checkState"));
     return result;
}
```

but when in qml I do

```
 console.log('checkstaterole',model.checkState)
```

in my delegate in qml, it says 'checkstaterole undefined'.

Why is it not possible to use the CheckStateRole in a QFileSystemModel? I thought every model derived from QAbstractItemModel has this role.

Comment: Hm, `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()` doesn't seem to be a virtual function. And is `checkState` a model's function?

Comment: it is virtual, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames (a bit hidden to the right). I thought you can access the models roles in qml via model.roleName

Comment: Ok, I just checked the implementation of qfilesystemmodel. it simply does not return anything for the Qt::CheckStateRole

Comment: @numberCruncher see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178597/how-to-add-a-custom-role-to-qfilesystemmodel/50180682#50180682, 
It seems that the 2 are working on the same. :P

Comment: thanks for the post

Comment: @numberCruncher If that answer helps you, do not forget to give it an upvote :D