# How to add a custom role to QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qfilesystemmodel

I would like to add a custom role to a QFileSystemModel (probably to a derived model). I want to use this role to save the check state of a CheckBox which is displayed next to the filename in a custom delegate. How can this be done?

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I think this its an elegant and easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used using the example [Qt Quick Controls - File System Browser Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html) removing the part of the selection.

The steps were the following:

- Add a new role in `roleNames`:

  ```
  QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
  {
      QHash<int, QByteArray> result = QFileSystemModel::roleNames();
      result.insert(SizeRole, QByteArrayLiteral("size"));
      result.insert(DisplayableFilePermissionsRole, QByteArrayLiteral("displayableFilePermissions"));
      result.insert(LastModifiedRole, QByteArrayLiteral("lastModified"));
      result.insert(Qt::CheckStateRole, QByteArrayLiteral("checkRole"));
      return result;
  }
  ```
- Create a container that stores the information of the selection, in this case I will use `QMap`:

  ```
  QMap<QPersistentModelIndex, Qt::CheckState> m_checks;
  ```
- Overwrite the `data()` method that returns the state if it is stored in the container, if it is not returned `Qt::UnChecked` as the default value:

  ```
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
  {
      if (index.isValid() && role >= SizeRole) {
          ...
      }
      else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
          QPersistentModelIndex pix(index);
          if(m_checks.contains(pix)){
              return m_checks[pix];
          }
          return Qt::Unchecked;
      }
      return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
  }
  ```
- Overwrite the `setData()` method, which you must modify if necessary and create the data.

  ```
  bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role=Qt::EditRole){
      if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.isValid()){

          Qt::CheckState current = value.value<Qt::CheckState>();
          if(m_checks.contains(index)){
              Qt::CheckState last = m_checks[index];
              if(last == current)
                  return false;
              m_checks[index] = current;
          }
          else{
              m_checks.insert(index, current);
          }
          emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});
          return true;
      }
      return QFileSystemModel::setData(index, value, role);
  }
  ```
- I have added a new column where I have established the delegate to the `CheckBox` and I used the `onCheckedChanged` slot to set the value using the `setData()` method, the `QModelIndex` is passed, the data and the role, in this case, pass 10 because it is the value number of `Qt::CheckStateRole`.

  ```
  TreeView {
      id: view
      model: fileSystemModel
      ...

      TableViewColumn {
          role: "checkRole"
          delegate: Component {
              CheckBox {
                  id: mycbx
                  checked: styleData.value
                  onCheckedChanged: view.model.setData(styleData.index, checked, 10)
              }
          }
      }
  ...
  ```

---

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/50178597-filesystembrowser).